# How to fetch particular data from api using php

Tags: php, api, curl

I am new in fetching data using APIs and need to fetch some particular columns data from a number of columns available. I am able to fetch all the data using API but wondering how to fetch particular columns. Below is my code:

```
<?php
$url = 'myurl';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"username\": \"test\", \"password\": \"test\"}",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "accept: application/json",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);

if ($result) {
    $data = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
    foreach ($data->Item as $entry) {
    echo "XML Activity Name: " . $entry->ActivityName . "<br>";
}
} else {
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't unless their API allows it to, so filter it out manually.

Comment: It depend  completly with the API from witch you are fetching data, the only thing you have to do is to fetch from the correct URL and the API will respond with the result which must be retrieved when that URL is the target. Else you will still have the same result with all the data if you are targetting the bad URL

Comment: My question is that if there are say 100 columns in API then how can I fetch 2 out of 100 and I don't think manual will do because I need to fetch the data for every session so that users can see their data.
Above code is giving all the results present in API